# Strip a part of an URL (qtranslate / woocommerce)

Tags: woocommerce

Is there a way in php to get rid of a specific parameter in an URL?

E.g: I have this link which activates a printing option in Wordpress Woocommerce frontend.
I am using mqtranslate to have two different languages.

> ...
>   myaccount/?lang=en%2Fprint-order%2F2067%2F&print-order-type=receipt

but this gives me an error, because there is

> /?lang=en

inside of the URL which should be at the end of the URL to work correct like this:

/?lang=en

I have already found the code which produces this - it's inside woocommerce/templates/myaccount/my-orders.php at line 87

```
$actions = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', $actions, $order );
if ($actions) {
    foreach ( $actions as $key => $action ) {
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $action['url'] ) . '" class="button ' . sanitize_html_class( $key ) . '">' . esc_html( $action['name'] ) . '</a>';
```

I tried to change $action into another url, but then printing is not working.

A working url would look like this:

> .../myaccount/print-order/2083/?print-order-type=receipt&lang=en

so how could I remove "?lang=en" in the beginning of the url and set it to the end of the url like "&lang=en"?

is there any way to do it in PHP or should I use jquery?

edit: maybe something like

> $('td.order-actions a.print').each(function(){
>           this.href = this.href.replace('?lang=en', '');

could also do the trick maybe, but I am not sure how to remove the "slashes" //.

Would this be the right way to remove lang=en? How can I then put it at the end?

EDIT 2:

Ok I found a solution - but it's not perfect:
I have a problem with jquery syntax in an url link:

this is the link i am getting:

> ...myaccount/?lang=en%2Fprint-order%2F2067%2F?print-order-type=receipt

I am using

> $('td.order-actions a.print').each(function(){
>           this.href = this.href.replace('/\?lang=en', '');

to remove the "/?lang=en"

the problem now is, that the link looks ok in my browser

> myaccount/print-order/2067/?print-order-type=receipt

but actually there's always a "%2F" instead of a "/" inside the link when I copy it which leads to the problem of getting an 404.

When I manually replace "%2F" the link works.

Where is the problem? Any idea to fix this?